# Apple Pay. Pay with a delay?

Tags: ios, delay, payment, applepay

Does Apple Pay to pay with a delay?

For example a passenger books a taxi, said he would use the Apple Pay. Use Touch id, and the payment occurs when the passenger arrives at their destination when already know the price of the trip. Is that possible?

How to implement it?

Can use the token obtained earlier from Touch id and then use with delay it to pay?

Comment: Have a look at this 
    https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/Getting-Started-with-Apple-Pay.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, apple requires their partners that accept apple pay are capable of authorizations, and capture. The authorization places the hold on the customers account, and the capture initiates the transfer. Typically the capture is done immediately for most transactions, but it is optional. The user would only need to enter their touchId during the authorization, no further action would be required on their part for the capture.

If you only perform an authorization and do not capture the charge then the hold will drop off after a certain period, I know it is 7 days for my payment system. Implementing this will vary based on your payment provider.